# Entity Framework and connecting tables at runtime

Tags: entity-framework

I have to process one dataset and migrate it to different dataset. Steps are as follow
1. I have a configuration table which contains names of tables and also other  table that contains configuration and mapping of columns from source to destination

**Select tablename,tablecode from tablemapping**

**Select columnname,columnmapping from columnmapping where tablecode=1**

2. Then make query to each table (tablenames) resulted from first select query

Using Microsoft data-access library I have done it some years back now have some changes in requirement and now we want use EF. How i can access tables that I don't know at compile time

Answer (score 0):

EF is not supposed to do that.

Basically, EF is supposed to map your tables to classes or classes to tables. Even if you find a method to generate a model in runtime what can you do with this classes, after compilation?

If you really want to use EF you schould use a dependency injection, and inject your context into application. But this context schould be prepared to each case separately.